# array convert string to array angularjs

Tags: javascript, angular

```
$scope.stringArray = new Array();
  angular.forEach($scope.questions, function(value, key){
      if(value.type == 'select') {
          var string = value.value;
          console.log(string) //"This is item";
          for(var i =0; i < string.length; i++){
              $scope.stringArray.push(string[i]);
              if(i != string.length-1){
                  $scope.stringArray.push(" ");
              }
          }

      }
  });
```

it should return

```
stringArray [0] = "This"; stringArray [1] = "is"; stringArray [2] = "item";
```

Currently response is like that

```
stringArray [0] = "T"; stringArray [1] = ""; stringArray [4] = "h"; stringArray [5] = ""; stringArray [6] = "i";...  Please guide
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`String.prototype.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split).

```
$scope.stringArray = string.split(" ");
```

The issue with your code is that, when you loop through a string `index 0` will give you the first character, `index 1` will give you the second character. It tokenizes the string based on characters and not on words.

`.split(" ")` will tokenize the string by spaces and will return an array.

Answer (score 0):

You need to split your `string` by `' '` and add them into the array

```
var string = value.value.split(' '); // <- split
for(var i = 0; i < string.length; i++){
    $scope.stringArray.push(string[i]);
    if(i != string.length-1) {
       $scope.stringArray.push(" ");
    }
}
```